$LDL^T$ factorization and iterative refinement
I have to solve the system $Ax = b$ where $A$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite.
The following assumes that no floating-point arithmetic errors occur.
$A$ is factored using $LDL^T$ algorithm with the following custom step:
if a pivot $d_i$ is too small, replace it with $\tilde{d_i} = d_i + \delta$.
Using the above factorization, I get the solution $\bar{x}$ for which
$LDL^T\bar{x} = b$
but
$A\bar{x} - b = r$
Custom step should be almost equivalent to factorize the matrix
$\tilde{A} = A + S$, where $S$ is diagonal with entries $0$ or $\delta$, with standard $LDL^T$ algorithm.
Now the idea is to use some sort of iterative refinement to get zero residual.
Standard schema for refinement is to set
$u = \bar{x} - c$
where
$\tilde{A}c = r$
After some substitutions I get
$Au = b + Sc$
With another refinement step
$w = u - c_2$
where
$\tilde{A}c_2 = Sc$
At the end residual becomes $Sc_2$, smaller than original one but not $0$.
Is it a robust solution? Are there other ways to refine the solution, perhaps using knowledge of $S$ a priori?

@Balajisb you are right! I've fixed my question. Thx.
